# Problem with VisualVM-when connecting to remote host

Tags: java, visualvm

I am new to Java Development and using the VisualVm for the first time.  I am facing some problem in Connecting a Remote Host from the VisualVm interface.

I have JDK 1.6 running in the remote host and also started jstatd server on the same. When I am connecting the remote host from  VisualVm interface running in local machine, its getting connected but the Profiler tab and Threads tab are missing from the interface. What can likely be the problem.

My OS is SUSE Linux.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The profiler tab is only available for local JVM's.

I'm not sure why the thread tab isn't displayed.  It does for me.

I've read that [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/profiler.html) has remote profiling support.  But I've never personally used it.

Comment: I did not find any official documentation mentioning profiling is only available for local JVMs, I hope what you are saying is not true :)

Comment: I found this: "From now you can use VisualVM to profile almost any Java application no matter if it's a locally running Sun JDK application or a remote IBM JDK-powered application server!" source:http://java.dzone.com/announcements/visualvm-12-great-java

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to monitor Jboss 4.0.2, since that version has its own mbean server , is this your case ?
Anyway, make sure you are using jdk 1.6.0u7 or later, otherwise you have to turn-off class sharing in order for visualvm to work (-Xshare:off)

I hope this helps, maybe you can give more details on the nature of application your trying to profile/JVM you are using